# How to grab webpage table data (using span class element) into listview control in vb.net 2008 app?

Tags: html, vb.net

I need to grab some data from a webpage but for me the main problem is I can’t grab the data the way I want. I want to grab the data in a listview control but my code is fetching all data within any span tag (span class “inputFieldLabel” which is not required) in a single column of a listview control.
I am giving the format (source) of the webpage below and my coding in vb.net (2008), please let me know where I am doing wrong.

```
<br>
<span class="inputFieldLabel">Following Are …</span> 
<span class="inputFieldLabel">01/02/2011</span>
<span class="inputFieldLabel">And</span>
<span class="inputFieldLabel">18/02/2012</span>  
<br>   
<tr>
<td class="cTableBorder">
<span class="displayTable">1</span>
</td>
<td class=" cTableBorder ">
<form id="Agent_No_1" action="https://..." method="post">
<input type="hidden" name="Agent_No" value="490848367">
<span class="displayTable">490848367</span>
</td>
<td class="cTableBorder ">
<span class="displayTable">20000</span> 
</td>
<td class="cTableBorder ">
<span class="displayTable">564.00</span> 
</td>
<td class="cTableBorder ">
<span class="displayTable">15/02/2011</span>            
</td>
```

```
<tr>
<td class="cTableBorder">
<span class="displayTable">2</span>
</td>
<td class=" cTableBorder ">
<form id="Agent_No_1" action="https://..." method="post">
<input type="hidden" name="Agent_No" value="490842352">
<span class="displayTable">490842352</span>
</td>
<td class="cTableBorder ">
<span class="displayTable">40000</span> 
</td>
<td class="cTableBorder ">
<span class="displayTable">774.00</span> 
</td>
<td class="cTableBorder ">
<span class="displayTable">15/02/2012</span>            
</td>
</tr>
```

Now my code is

```
Private Sub Button6_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button6.Click


Dim allelements As HtmlElementCollection = WebBrowser1.Document.GetElementsByTagName("span") 
For Each DD As HtmlElement In allelements
If DD.OuterHtml.Contains("displayTable") Then
Dim z As ListViewItem
z = New ListViewItem(DD.GetAttribute("InnerText")) 
ListView1.Items.Add(z)
End If
Next
End Sub
```

Answer (score 1):

I have solved my issue. Here is my code sample which is working.

```
Dim outputstream As StreamWriter = File.CreateText("c:\listview.txt")

Dim allelements As HtmlElementCollection = WebBrowser1.Document.GetElementsByTagName("td")

For Each DD As HtmlElement In allelements

If DD.GetAttribute("className") = ("cTableBorder ") Then

outputstream.WriteLine(DD.GetAttribute("InnerText"))

End If

Next

outputstream.Close()
```